# A big class of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

During my researches, I've obtained a class of finite groups as follows.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of all finite groups $G$ such that for every factorization $|G|=ab$ there exists a subgroup $H\neq G$ such that $|G:H|$ divides $a$ or $b$ (equivalentely, $a$ or $b$ divides $|H|$).

We are looking for some classes of groups (resp. special groups)  **inside** (resp. **outside**) $\mathcal{C}$.

For example, the class of all finite solvable groups, and also groups $G$ such that for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$
there is a subgroup of the order or index $d$ (containing all CLT and supersolvable groups) is a sub-class of $\mathcal{C}$ (see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961921/a-gap-code-for-a-class-of-small-groups).

Now, my questions are:

**(1)** What is the minimum of sizes of all groups outside $\mathcal{C}$?

**(2)** Is the class of all finite simple groups a sub-class of $\mathcal{C}$?

**(3)** Does anybody know some other vast sub-classes of $\mathcal{C}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't Hall subgroups immediately imply (2)?

Comment: @-Steve D. You are right, I've changed it now.

Comment: It fails for ${\rm PSL}(2,8)$ with $a=12$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Is it the smallest size?